# How to programmatically set Webform field value with custom submit?

Tags: 8, webforms

I try to update an hidden field value with my custom submit, but it doesn't work, my new value are not saved.

With :  `$form_state->setValue('token_uid', $token_uid);`

```
  function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == 'webform_submission_creation_compte_add_form' || $form_id == 'webform_submission_creation_compte_test_form') {

      foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
        //attention en multi step : wizard_next
        if ($action != 'wizard_next' && $action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
          $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = '_MODULE_creation_compte_submit';
        }
      }
      if (isset($form['#validate'])) {
        $form['#validate'][]  =  '_MODULE_creation_compte_validate';
      }
    }
  }
```

My custom submit function :

```
function _MODULE_creation_compte_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    global $base_url;
    $data               = array();
    $user_id_created    = null;

    //Info account
    $account_name       = $form_state->getValue('nom');
    $account_username   = $form_state->getValue('username');
    $account_first_name = $form_state->getValue('prenom');
    $account_mail       = $form_state->getValue('email');
    $account_password   = $form_state->getValue('mot_de_passe');
    $account_phone      = $form_state->getValue('telephone');


    if (!empty($account_username) && !empty($account_password) && !empty($account_mail)) {

        $account_username   = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $account_username)).'_'.rand(0,1000);

        $user_created       = User::create([
          'name'                  => $account_username,
          'pass'                  => $account_password,
          'mail'                  => $account_mail,
          'field_user_nom'        => $account_name,
          'field_user_prenom'     => $account_first_name,
          'field_user_telephone'  => $account_phone['phone'],
          'status'                => 0,
          'init'                  => $account_mail,
          'created'               => time(),
          'changed'               => time(),
          'login'                 => 0,
          'access'                => 0,
        ]);
        $user_created->save();
        $user_id_created = $user_created->id();
        $token_uid       =  $base_url . '/user/' . $user_id_created;

       //==> Value is not saved after submit
        $form_state->setValue('token_uid', $token_uid);

    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: My field  'token_uid' value are not saved

Comment: It probably wouldn't in an appended submit function, the entity has already been updated by that point. You can change the value in a validate method instead, implement `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave` instead, or try forcing your submit method to the front of the list with `array_unshift`

Comment: Maybe the best way to achieve this is to try to make a custom Handlers (I try webform_submission_presave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) ...)  : https://fr.slideshare.net/philipnorton42/webform-and-drupal-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution with `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave`** :

```
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

 function MODULE_webform_submission_presave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission){
    global $base_url;
    $user_id_created    = null;

    //Info account
    $account_name       = $webform_submission->getElementData('nom');
    $account_username   = $webform_submission->getElementData('username');
    $account_first_name = $webform_submission->getElementData('prenom');
    $account_mail       = $webform_submission->getElementData('email');
    $account_password   = $webform_submission->getElementData('mot_de_passe');
    $account_phone      = $webform_submission->getElementData('telephone');

    if (!empty($account_username) && !empty($account_password) && !empty($account_mail)) {

      $account_username   = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $account_username)).'_'.rand(0,1000);

      $user_created       = User::create([
        'name'                  => $account_username,
        'pass'                  => $account_password,
        'mail'                  => $account_mail,
        'field_user_nom'        => $account_name,
        'field_user_prenom'     => $account_first_name,
        'field_user_telephone'  => $account_phone['phone'],
        'status'                => 0,
        'init'                  => $account_mail,
        'created'               => time(),
        'changed'               => time(),
        'login'                 => 0,
        'access'                => 0,
      ]);
      $user_created->save();
      $user_id_created = $user_created->id();
      $token_uid       =  $base_url .'/user/' . $user_id_created;
      $webform_submission->setElementData('token_uid', $token_uid);
    }
  }
```